# Minimize activity on back key press

Tags: android, minimize, onkeydown

`OnBack` Key press i want to minimize the application, **How can i do
this???**

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

           //Here i want to put minimize code.. pls give me this statement

       return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

}

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "minimize"? Do you want to run code when leaving the activity? If so, you should put that code in onPause or onStop, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Thank you for reply. suppose there is a EditText box in my main activity, and i entered values to that field during running the activity. At that time if i press Back key, i want to minimize the application, so that i can see the values if i open that application once again.

Comment: I would use onStop to write the data to file/preference/database, and read the data in the onStart method.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
         {
            this.moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
         }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

This will send the activity to the background. See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29) for further reference.