# How to hide my application window in android?

Tags: android, window

How to hide my application window through programmatically?

Is it possible?

```
setContentView( R.layout.screen1 );
```

This coding to start application window. How to hide this window. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: May be you are looking for [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6620329/593709)

Comment: -1 Too many duplicates of this question already. Please use the search function instead of asking new questions.

Comment: You can make your search Android specific by typing `[android]` and any other search terms in the search box in the top right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this,

**MainActivity.java**

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Put you code to hide the layout
        RelativeLayout mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        mLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah its possible. Provide an id to the parent window of screen1 layout like:

```
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
```

and when you want to hide it, write something like:

```
final LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.main_layout); // assuming its a LinearLayout

mainLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I think you can also hide an activity by setting an attribute to it in xml like..android:visibility="gone"